# (Android Studio) WebView fica carrega a página e não abre

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, webview

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que reúne alguns site, porem alguns deles fica carregando no WebView  e não abre. Como exemplo vou usar o site da [UrPay](https://conta.urpay.com.br/entrar).
Já vi esse site sendo aberto por outro aplicativo, por sinal abre normalmente como se você no Google Chrome.

> Arquivo .xml

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Mibank_Activity">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_Urpay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> Arquivo .java

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urpay_);

    setTitle("URPAY");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_Urpay);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://conta.urpay.com.br/entrar");
}
```

O site fica carregando e nunca abre. Isso seria configuração do meu WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona essa mano aqui que vai dar bom
       " webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); "
sua classe ficará assim

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_urpay_);

setTitle("URPAY");

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_Urpay);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://conta.urpay.com.br/entrar");
```

}